# Woocommerce - filter shipping rates by date

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hide specific shopping rates during the weekdays and offer them only on weekend (friday evening to be exact). I have 5 rates, I would like to show first 3 (by id ) always and rate 4 and 5 only on friday afternoon and night.

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_friday_special_shipping_method', 10, 2 );

    function hide_friday_special_shipping_method ( $rates, $package ) {

             if ( date("N")==5 && date("G")>=15 || date("N")==6 && date("G")<=8) {


            foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            if ( '5' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
               = array();
  }
foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            if ( '4' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
               = array();
  }
  return $rates;
}
```

It doesnt return anything. Could you please advice me on what should i do ?

```
function hide_friday_special_shipping_method ( $rates ) {

    if ( date("N")==4 && date("G")>=1 || date("N")==6 && date("G")<=8) {

            $rates = unset($rates[3]);
            $rates = unset($rates[4]);

  }
  return $rates;
}

print_r($rates);
```

Tried this but it doesnt work either..